# The relation between the irreducible representations of $SO(3)$ and totally symmetric tensor?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, tensors

I read that the dimension of the irreducible representations of $SO(3)$ is the dimension of the totally symmetric tensor$S^{i_1i_2...i_j}$ in A.Zee's book. But, in fact, the group's tensor representation can break up into many different inreducible tensors.
For example, for a $2$-rank tensor representation:
$$
9=5\oplus3\oplus1
$$
$5$ is the dimension of symmetric traceless tensor, $3$ the antisymmetric tensor, $1$ is the trace.

So, why the dimension of the irreducible representaions of $SO(3)$ is $2j+1$, the dimension of totally symmetric tensor?

Comment: The representation theory of $SO(3)$ or equivalently of $\mathfrak{so}(3,\mathbb{C}) = \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is covered in almost every introductory textbook on Lie theory as it is the cornerstone of all other representations of semisimple Lie algebras and even their classifications. Note these representations can all be written in the form $S^{n}\mathbb{C}^2$ (with dimension $n+1$) which I suspect is what Zee means

Comment: Got it. It means j stand for the dimension of S, instead of the dimension of T?

Comment: I have no idea what T and S refer to I'm afraid

Comment: Reading your question again you specifically mention odd dimensional irreps and I think it is work noting that the tensor product of odd dimensional irreps of $SO(3)$ will decompose into only odd dimensional irreps. To see this note that the weights of an odd (resp. even) dimensional irrep are just even (resp. odd) numbers and the weights of a tensor product are just sums of the original weights so we have only even weights and thus only odd dimensional irreps.